# jquery get url from data and replace as href

Tags: jquery

I need some help with a javascript function. I have this script

```
$.get('http://ste.com/a-link.php', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

where `"data"` contains a link wich i need to use it as "a href".

For example,

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

When I click "link" the # from "a href" to be replaced with the url from "data"
Maybe someone get the idea and help me with this. I am a noob with javascript.

Comment: hint:  .attr('href', data);

Comment: I'm a bit disconcerted here. What's the real content of `data`? Can you post it in verbatim in your question? Are you adding a new `<a>` element or updating an existent `<a>` element?

Comment: yes 'data' is most likely json data comming back that contains the link you need , not just simply the link

Comment: the real content from data looks like this `http://sastreang.com/p/g52pldidrje_miuvuz_25d51605599253b04236ef9108.mp3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use jquery for this as it will provide with you built in methods that make things like this easier.

you would call this in your javascript most likely on document ready.
what was mentioned about the format of the data the is returned is valid. Most likely the script you will be calling will return data to you in json format which you will have to handle with javascript. This is easy using dot notation but required nonetheless. You would access it something like data.url

```
   $.get('http://ste.com/a-link.php', 
        function(data) {
           $('a').on("click", function(){
                  $(this).prop('href', data);     
               });
       });
```

Comment: indeed he is using it to make an httprequest. all i was saying was that it is useful in the context of needing to replace things in elements or set properties/attributes. sorry if i was unclear